# Raise to the Power

Tags: code-golf, math, restricted-source

#### Challenge

Challenge is writing a program that takes a **positive** numbers `a` and a **nonzero** number `b` and outputs `a^b` (a raised to the power b).  You can only use `+ - * / abs()` as mathematical functions/operators. These can only be applied to scalar values, but not to whole lists or arrays.

Examples:

```
1.234 ^ 5.678 = 3.29980
4.5   ^ 4.5   = 869.874
4.5   ^-4.5   = 0.00114959
```

Relevant: http://xkcd.com/217/

#### Details

You can write a function or a similar construct for using in console. If you cannot use console input you can assume that both numbers are saved in variables and ouptut via standard output or writing to a file. The output has to be correct to at least 4 significat digits. You can assume that both `a` and `b` are nonzero. A runtime of significantly more than 1 minute is not acceptable. The least number of bytes will win. Please explain your program and your algorithm.

EDIT: Only **positive bases** have to be considered. You can assume `a>0`. **Be aware that both numbers do not have to be integers!!!**

Comment: Are you asking us to raise to a decimal power? Like say, 4.5 ^ 4.5?

Comment: Does this mean we have to output imaginary numbers too if the base is negative?

Comment: What should the output for `-0.5 ** 0.5` be?

Comment: Ok I did not think of that case, thank you: Negative bases  must not be correctly implemented. @fuandon exactly, real numbers can have decimals (at least in most programming languages=)

Comment: I'd like to add a test case with b<0: `4.5 ^ -4.5 = 0.0011496'

Comment: Aw, Python's `e` syntax doesn't work with floats. :c

Comment: "positive numbers" -> "positive number"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Python, 77

As with some other answers this is based on log and exp. But the functions are computed by numerically solving ordinary differential equations.

```
def f(a,b,y=1):
 if a<1:a=1/a;b=-b
 while a>1:a/=1e-7+1;y*=b*1e-7+1
 return y
```

Does it satisfy the requirements? For the examples in the question, yes. For large a, it will take a very long time. For large a or b, it will become inaccurate.

Examples:

```
a            b            f(a, b)      pow(a, b)      <1e-5 rel error?
       1.234        5.678       3.2998       3.2998   OK
         4.5          4.5      869.873      869.874   OK
         4.5         -4.5   0.00114959   0.00114959   OK
         0.5          0.5     0.707107     0.707107   OK
         0.5         -0.5      1.41421      1.41421   OK
          80            5  3.27679e+09   3.2768e+09   OK
     2.71828      3.14159      23.1407      23.1407   OK
```

Update: flawr asked for more detail on the maths so here you go. I considered the following initial value problems:

- x'(t) = x(t), with x(0) = 1. The solution is exp(t).
- y'(t) = by(t), with y(0) = 1. The solution is exp(bt).

If I can find the value of t such that x(t) = a, then I'll have y(t) = exp(bt) = a^b. The simplest way to numerically solve an initial value problem is [Euler's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method). You compute the derivative the function is supposed to have, and then take a, step, in the *direction* of the derivative, and *proportional* to it, but scaled by a tiny constant. So that's what I do, take tiny steps until x is as big as a, and then see what y is at that time. Well, that's the way I thought of it. In my code, t is never explicitly computed (it is 1e-7 * the number of steps of the while loop), and I saved some characters by doing the calculations for x with a instead.

Comment: That looks great, I am happy to see another different approach! Can you tell us a bit more about these differential equations? I know generally what they are but I was not able to figure out how you program uses them=)

Comment: @flawr: OK, I updated with some more details about the maths.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (E6) 155 <s>174 191</s>

**Edit 2** As suggested by @bebe, using recursive function (performe worse but shorter)
Slightly changed R function to avoid 'too much recursion'
Test suite added. The function performs well for bases < 3000 and exponent in range -50..50.
**Edit** Golfed more and better precision

Any real number can be approximate with a rational number (and IEEE standard 'real' numbers store rationals in fact).
Any rational number can be expressed as a fraction a/b with a and b integers. x^(a/b) is root b of (x^a) or (root b of x)^a.
Integer exponentiation is quite easy by squaring.
Integer root can be approximated using numerical methods.

**Code**

```js
P=(x,e)=>(
  f=1e7,e<0&&(x=1/x,e=-e),
  F=(b,e,r=1)=>e?F(b*b,e>>1,e&1?r*b:r):r,
  R=(b,e,g=1,y=1e-30,d=(b/F(g,e-1)-g)/e)=>d>y|d<-y?R(b,e,g+d,y/.99):g,
  F(R(x,f),e*f)
)
```

**Test** In FireFox or FireBug console

```js
for (i=0;i<100;i++)
{
  b=Math.random()*3000
  e=Math.random()*100-50
  p1=Math.pow(b,e) // standard power function, to check
  p2=P(b,e)
  d=(p1-p2)/p1 // relative difference
  if (!isFinite(p2) || d > 0.001) 
    console.log(i, b, e, p1, p2, d.toFixed(3))
}
```

Comment: Good job, not terribly precise but it the algorithm is nice=)

Comment: Can you explain what this `e&1&&(r*=b)` does, except multiplying `r` by `b`?

Comment: @flawr `if(e&1 != 0) r *= b`

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that exploit, but it seems to be a nice one for golfing=)

Comment: oh and 149:
`P=(x,e,f=1<<24)=>(e<0&&(x=1/x,e=-e),((b,e,r=1)=>e?F(b*b,e>>1,e&1?r*b:r):r)(((b,e,g=1,y=1e-16)=>(d=(b/F(g,e-1)-g)/e,d>y|d<-y?R(b,e,g+d):g))(x,f),e*f))`

Comment: @bebe unbelievable (and ununderstandable... recursion instead of loops?)

Comment: sorry for bothering you again but i forgot to name the two functions. this is valid: `P=(x,e,f=1<<24)=>(e<0&&(x=1/x,e=-e),((b,e,r=1)=>e?F(b*b,e>>1,e&1?r*b:r):r)(((b,e,g=1,y=1e-16)=>(d=(b/F(g,e-1)-g)/e,d>y|d<-y?R(b,e,g+d):g))(x,f),e*f))` i hope you can golf down more (tweet size maybe?) by losing precision and skipping operations (that i honestly don't understand)

Comment: @bebe don't leave this way!U posted the same code...

Comment: here's the working code: `P=(x,e)=>(F=(b,e,r=1)=>e?F(b*b,e>>1,e&1?r*b:r):r,R=(b,e,g=1,y=1e-16,d=(b/F(g,e-1)-g)/e)=>d>y|d<-y?R(b,e,g+d):g,e<0&&(x=1/x,e=-e),f=1<<24,F(R(x,f),e*f))` (i must be tired)

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, 85 <s>90</s>

Standard exp-log algorithm.  Now with different name, shaving off a few more characters:

```hs
a%b|a>1=1/(1/a)%b|0<1=sum$scanl((/).((-b*foldr1(\n b->(1-a)*(b+1/n))c)*))1c
c=[1..99]
```

`raise` is now called `(%)`, or `%` in infix notation, even making its use consume fewer bytes: `4.5%(-4.5)`

The ungolfed version also uses just 172 bytes:

```hs
raise a b | a > 1     = 1 / raise (1/a) b
          | otherwise = expo (-b* ln (1-a))

ln x = foldr1 (\n a -> x*a+x/n) [1..99]

expo x = sum $ scanl ((/) . (x*)) 1 [1..99]
```

Answer (score 4):

### JS (ES6), 103 bytes

```js
t=(x,m,f)=>{for(r=i=s=u=1;i<1<<7+f;r+=s/(u=i++*(f?1:u)))s*=m;return r};e=(a,b)=>t(b,t(a,1-1/a,9)*b-b,0)
```

Examples :

```
e(1.234,5.678) = 3.299798925315965
e(4.5,4.5)     = 869.8739233782269
e(4.5,-4.5)    = 0.0011495918812070608
```

Use Taylor series.
`b^x = 1 + ln(b)*x/1! + (ln(b)*x)^2/2! + (ln(b)*x)^3/3! + (ln(b)*x)^4/4! + ...`
with [natural logarithm approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Derivative.2C_Taylor_series) :
`ln(b) = (1-1/x) + (1-1/x)^2/2 + (1-1/x)^3/3 + (1-1/x)^4/4 + ...`

I used 128 iterations to compute `b^x` (more iterations is difficult due to factorial) and 262144 iterations for `ln(b)`

Comment: Maybe you should golf less but add more precision: `e(80,5) ->1555962210.2240903` - should be 3276800000

Comment: @edc65, you're right, fixed for 5 more chars.

Comment: It's very nice to see some different approaches!

Answer (score 3):

## [golflua](http://mniip.com/misc/conv/golflua/) 120

I use the fact that

```
a^b = exp(log(a^b)) = exp(b*log(a))
```

and wrote my own `log` & `exp` functions. The values `a` and `b` need to be entered on newlines when run in the terminal:

```
\L(x)g=0~@ i=1,50 c=(x-1)/x~@j=2,i c = c*(x-1)/x$g=g+c/i$~g$\E(x)g=1;R=1e7~@i=1,R g=g*(1+x/R)$~g$a=I.r()b=I.r()w(E(b*L(a)))
```

Sample runs:

```
4.5, 4.5  ==> 869.87104890175
4.5, -4.5 ==> 0.0011495904124065
3.0, 2.33 ==> 12.932794624815
9.0, 0.0  ==> 1
2.0, 2.0  ==> 3.9999996172672
```

An ungolfed Lua version is,

```
-- returns log
function L(x)
   g = 0
   for i=1,50 do
      c=(x-1)/x
      for j=2,i do
         c = c*(x-1)/x
      end
      g = g + c/i
   end
   return g
end

-- returns exp
function E(x)
   g=1;L=9999999
   for i=1,L do
      g=g*(1+x/L)
   end
   return g
end

a=io.read()
b=io.read()

print(E(b*L(a)))
print(a^b)
```

Comment: Can you provide some example outputs?

Comment: @flawr: I suppose I can...and now done